# Displaying data from db in table form laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to display all menus from the db in table form however i got an error saying that "undefined variable:menus(0)"

dashboard_index.blade.php

```
 <div class= "menu-content">
  <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col">Category Code</th>
        <th scope="col">Menu Title</th>
        <th scope="col">Menu Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach ($menus as $menu)
      <tr>
        <td>{{ $menu->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $menu->category_code }}</td>
        <td>{{ $menu->menu_title }}</td>
        <td>RM{{ $menu->menu_price }}</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/dashboard', 'AdminMenuController@index');
```

AdminMenuController.php

```
    public function index()
{
    $menus = \App\Menu::all();
    return view('admin.dashboard_index',      
    [
        'menus'=>$menus,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your code as text and not as image to ensure your question is still helpful even if the images are deleted?

Comment: Please post the code as text and not as pictures

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error in `$menu = \App\Menu::all()`

it should be `$menus = \App\Menu::all()`

Comment: That's not a syntax error, it's merely a typo. And we generally don't answer typo questions (because they hold no long term value, they only help the OP). We leave a comment under the question and flag the question as a typo (`Flag` > `needs improvement` > `A community-specific reason` > `Not reproducible or was caused by a typo`).

Comment: just realized, corrected it but i still got the same error

Comment: try @dd(menus) and tell me what comes up

Comment: it gives me an error "Use of undefined constant menus - assumed 'menus'"

Comment: @dd($menus); 
I'm sorry, I'm not using IDE here so you need to check the syntax after me

Comment: still the same error  "undefined variable:menus(0)" ; sorry im new into laravel T_T;

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what could be the issue, maybe if I could see the entire code I could help